# Java Mail: Converting attachment data failed

Tags: jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I want to send Files using Java Mail, I have the next code:

Here I download the file from Google Drive in InputStream.

```
File file = DriveHelper.getFile("oalsdiañsdluioumadsspdmaasd-asdoiasd");
InputStream inputStream = DriveHelper.downloadFile(file);
```

After that I write the next code:

```
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
String htmlBody = "hello world";        // ...
// convert inputstream to byte[]
byte[] attachmentData = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();

MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
htmlPart.setContent(htmlBody, "text/html");
mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
attachment.setFileName("archivo.pdf");
attachment.setContent(attachmentData, "application/pdf");
mp.addBodyPart(attachment);
message.setContent(mp);
Transport.send(message);
```

But when I run the code I have next Exception:

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Send failure (javax.mail.MessagingException: Converting attachment data failed)
[INFO]  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:163)
[INFO]  at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
```

Comment: Are you running in GAE?  I believe GAE has restrictions on the kinds of messages you can send and the kinds of attachments you're allowed to send.

Comment: Yes I running in GAE, but in here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/#Java_Sending_mail_with_attachments , says I can send MIME type "application/pdf".

Answer (score 0):

attachment.setContent() does not work properly.

You can use DataSource:

```
        MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        attachment.setFileName("archivo.pdf");
        DataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(inputStream, "application/pdf");
        attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(dataSource));
        mp.addBodyPart(attachment);
```

Comment: You could be right, GAE may be using an old version of javax.activation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this link: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.appengine.api.mail.MailService, and solved my problem.